# Can I force install memsql with offline media?

Tags: singlestore

I try to deploy MemSQL in a restricted environment with limited Internet access, but the network is still accessible to Internet and can not be down.

I have no problem to use `memsql-ops file-add -t memsql` to add offline media. But the `memsql-deploy` sub-command still always try to download newer version from Internet.

In past, I can force `memsql-deploy` implicitly to use offline media by put down the Internet facing NIC. But how can I **force memsql install only using offline media** without put down the network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use memsql-deploy --version-hash HASH to install a specific version. HASH can be found in memsqlbin/utils/build_receipt.json as memsql_version_hash (http://docs.memsql.com/docs/build-receipt-schema). This will ensure it uses the file you added, instead of trying to download a different version.

Comment: This worked and it is what is expected. I believe this info is worthy to be included in the "full installation guide". That will help the others.